# How can I make a basic calculator with 8086 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, calculator, x86-16

I have 2 variables equal to 3 and 5. The user should type a math operator at which point the program returns the result of the operation.

For example, if user enters `*`, the program should output `15`. I'm a newbie at Assembly.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Draw a flowchart first, or write out what you want to do in "pseudocode".  Then figure out how to convert to assembly.  And when you have it about 2/3rds written, throw out what you have and start over, since by then you'll understand the problem better.  (It's been about 30 years since I did any 8086 assembler, so that's about the only advice I can give you.)

Comment: BTW, you first need to decide whether you'll be using [infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) or [postfix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) for your user interface.  (Postfix is easier to code and more powerful but a bit less intuitive for the user.)

Comment: Why do you have to do it in 8086 assembly, is this some kind of homework?

Answer (score 1):

```
start:
    a = 3
    b = 5
    i = input
    if i != '*' 
        goto not_mul
    r = a * b
    goto print_result
not_mul:
    if i != '/'
        goto not_div
    r = a / b
    goto print_result
not_div:
    ...
print_result:
    print r
    end
```

Translate line by line into your specific assembler.

Answer (score 1):

For programming in general, the first step is to define the problem. Will the calculator be a command line tool, or have a fancy GUI? Will it only do integer maths (e.g. "5/3 = 1") or use floating point (e.g. "5/3 = 1.6666667"), or perhaps use arbitrary size rational numbers to get extreme accuracy? Will it perform operations in the order they're entered, or keep track of the current formula and rearrange it to improve accuracy and/or performance and/or do operations in an order determined by operator precedence rules (e.g. "5 + 3 / 2 = 8 / 2 = 4" or "5 + 3 / 2 = 5 + 1.5 = 6.5")?

Next, break the (larger) problem into smaller problems, and keep doing this until you've got pieces that are small enough to implement as methods/functions/routines.

For example, "calculator" might be split into "user interface", "operator tracking" (e.g. keeping track of operations that the user has requested but haven't been performed yet due to precedence rules) and "operator handling". These pieces could be split further (e.g "user interface" might be split into "get operation from STDIN" and "display calculator state"; and "operator handling" might be split into "multiply", "divide", "add", etc).

Note: For assembly, these final pieces tend to be a bit smaller than they would in high level languages. It might be silly to have a "do_addition()" function in C, and might be silly not to have a "do_addition:" routine in assembly.

Once you've split everything up, write it down. This could be a set of UML diagrams, or a flowchart or something, or just a text file that describes things. It really depends on how long the software will be maintained and how complex it is (note: a command line "integer only" calculator can be very simple, while a high/infinite precision GUI calculator can be very complex).

Finally, implement all the little pieces. I tend to like working from the top down (e.g. start with the user interface), but working from the bottom up is equally good (e.g. start with routines to do addition, subtraction, etc). The important thing is being able to test what you've done as you go (which can involve writing temporary code to test what you've done, or implementing formal unit tests).